# Form message alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="contactus.php" name="myForm" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="60" required/>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="120" required/>

            <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" required></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />

        </form>
```

And some PHP that sends the email, the PHP is on the same page as the form (contactus.php), and I want a message to come up somewhere on the page (not a pop up please) to tell the user there email has been sent (the email doesn't need to be validated, just for when the button is pressed). This can be done in PHP, AJAX or JS I don't mind

Comment: You can use all 3 to accomplish this: 1. Create service to send email and return response code 2. Call service via AJAX 3. If response code ok then update html using javascript to display message...

Comment: So any chance you can provide any information to how that is done regarding my example? Literally just when the button is pressed, a message comes up saying "thank you"

Comment: Well you are using a form to submit to `contactus.php` instead of using a form I would pass your parameters to the same `contactus.php` file via an `AJAX` call. Then have the `contactus.php` return some sort of response like "ok" or "failed". In the success callback function of the `AJAX` call just check if the response is "ok" or "failed" then use `Javascript` to update the `HTML` to display an appropriate message...This isn't a simple thing I can just show you I can give you an example but it won't have all the code you need...

Comment: if all you want is a message (no validation that the email was actually received) that's easy you can use `Javascript` to do that...

Comment: @brso05 yeah I am quite new to coding, all I want is the message, if it is easy can you show me how?

Comment: yes give me a second and I will post something...

Comment: @brso05 why did you delete your answer?

Comment: because if you want to do it that way you would have to change how you are submitting the form in the first place I wasn't sure if you wanted to do that...

Comment: I wasn't thinking when I posted that...You would have to change somethings to get it to work.

Comment: @brso05 the way you did it looked how I wanted it, I literally just want a message to come up anywhere on the page saying thank you when the button is pressed

Comment: the problem is your submitting a form to a new page `contactus.php` so the javascript will run but it will reload `contactus.php` so fast you won't see it. Is `contactus.php` the page that you posted in your question(is it submitting to itself)?

Comment: What is the name of the page that has the above `form` in it?

Comment: @brso05 contactus.php, it is the same page for both form and php

Comment: So both the same page

Comment: Alright I'll post something you can try...

Comment: No problem man...I just posted it. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code --

```
<p style="display:none">Mail Send Successfully </p>
<form method="post" action="contactus.php" name="myForm" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="60" required/>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="120" required/>

            <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" required></textarea>

            <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />

        </form>
```

AJAX Code --

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit-btn').click(function(){
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var message = $('#message').val();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "form-submit.php", // in this file we will put the code of send email and also we will return a response
                data:"name="+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message,
                success: function(response) // we will get response
                    {
                        $('p').show(); // here message will show after send email
                    }
              }); 
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: What did you mean by "and also we will return a response"?

Comment: form-submit.php file will return a response like if(email_send) { echo "Success"; } // it will be response

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="contactus.php?message=ok" name="myForm" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="60" required/>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="120" required/>

    <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" required</textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
<div id="displayMessage"></div>*****************new div to display message put wherever you want******************
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        if(getParameterByName("message") == "ok")
        {
            document.getElementById("displayMessage").innerHTML = "Message Sent.";
            window.alert("Message Sent.");//If you want an alert box
        }
<script>
```

Just put the `<script></script>` at the end of your body...

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it will work but doesn't, when I press the button the email sends, page reloads and nothing changes

Comment: @Thomas sorry ya I wan't thinking you are submitting via form try what Jeff said...

Comment: @Thomas notice the `contactus.php?message=ok`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is working. I think I am having some problem with CSS as now I cannot see the message. and I use 'find' to try and find the text but it isn't anywhere on the page

Comment: @Thomas is the alert working?

Comment: @Thomas try leaving this: `document.getElementById("displayMessage").innerHTML = "Message Sent.";` out and see if the `window.alert("Message Sent.");` works...

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP that sends mail is on the same page, I'm assuming a structure like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email') {
    mail("name@example.com", "subject", "text");
}
?>
```

I recommend you add a variable there, like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email') {
    mail("name@example.com", "subject", "text");
    $sent_mail = true; // so we know later
}
?>
```

Then somewhere in the page, do this:

```
<?php
if (isset($sent_mail)) {
    echo 'Success!';
}
?>
```

No javascript needed :)

Comment: This looks like it should work, but the 'success' doesn't show anywhere

Comment: Verify that you submit the form to the same place. Verify that the variable gets set. Verify that the print statement is in the right place. Hopefully one of those is the problem

Comment: Where should the print statement be?

Comment: Wherever you'd like the success message to appear in your page. This method will show it after you submit the form, on the next page load which I'm assuming is how this setup works. If you're submitting via AJAX, it won't work and you should use a Javascript method like saurav greg suggested.

Comment: Yeah the page loads, I have the statement in a new div but the message doesn't show

Comment: Can you put an `echo` statement in the same code block that sends the mail? You need to make sure that variable (`$sent_mail`) is being set.

Comment: The message is sent because I have received the email, but nothing happens with the echo statement for some reason. I have it echoing success once the email is sent, but nothing echoes

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem. What would you like to be echoed?

Comment: Just a thank you message

Comment: Awesome - a better thank-you is accepting my answer for those sweet, sweet internet points :)

Comment: Nothing has been accepted because it hasn't been fixed..

Comment: Jeff the echo message is now showing so the message is sending, but the php statement isn't

Comment: Make sure the variable `$sent_mail` is being set and read in the same variable scope

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that

Comment: Read about variable scope here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I used the exact code you used in your answer

Comment: That's fine, but you need to make sure PHP can see the `$sent_mail` variable *where you're trying to echo it*. What are you seeing now?

Comment: I still don't really know how to test that