# PHP Form Message

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="contactus.php?message=ok" name="myForm" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="60" required/>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="120" required/>

    <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" onsubmit="displayMessage()" />
```

And the code to send the email:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["submit"]) { 
  // The message
  $message=$_POST["message"];   
  $email=$_POST["email"];
  // In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use    wordwrap()
  $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
  // Send
  mail('myemail.co.uk', $email, $message);
  $sent_mail = true;
}
?>
```

And finally:

```
<?php
if (isset($sent_mail)) {
  echo 'Thank you. We will be in touch soon.';
}
?>
```

So when the email is sent, sent_mail is set to 'true' and therefore the thank you message should be echoed. But right now this isn't working. The email sends first but the thank you message doesn't show. I basically just need a thank you message to come up somewhere on the page when the submit button is pressed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do all these three codes in same file? I don't think. I expect form and "thank you" in same file, and code for mail in another file. Can you please update the code loactions/files.?

Comment: They are all in the same file, contactus.php

Comment: Can you update complete file contents.? Keep both your php codes inside single <?php  ?> frame. It works.

Comment: I tested your code in my server and it is working well. I didn't find any problems. Show your complete file code, as the problem is not with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form message alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995479/form-message-alert)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of isset use simply if

Like this

```
<?php
 if ($sent_mail) {
 echo 'Thank you. We will be in touch soon.';
 }
else
 echo 'Unale to send message';
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that kind of works. When I use 'find' the web page says it is there, but I cannot see the text anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`mail` function returns a boolean (true/false), so you can do like this

```
if (mail('myemail.co.uk', $email, $message)) {
    echo "Thank you. We will be in touch soon.";
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong, the email was not sent!";
}
```

Also, the structure of `mail` (the parameters) are to-address, subject, message. Which means that your current subject is the email-address, I'm not sure if this is what you intended?

Comment: Thank you. That should work but doesn't. Maybe because when the button is pressed the page is reloaded, so the thank you message doesn't show. Although when I use 'find' the web page says it is there, but I cannot see the text anywhere. And yes that is what I intend

Comment: The button from the form is pressed, then sends you to `contactus.php`. It's in that file you want to have the `mail` function. -- Are you reloading the page once the mail is sent again?

Comment: The page with the form is contactus.php, so everything is on contactus.php.

Comment: If everything is on the same page, you don't need the `action`-attribute on your form, but that's not relevant to your problem. -- If you action to the same page, it reloads, then checks if anything new has happened (Yes it has, `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))` has been set). This results that whatever is inside that bracket is done, which is also the `mail` function, right? If that's the case, it sends the email, so you don't need any more reloading, you can just display the message right there, with the code as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that kind of works. When I use 'find' the web page says it is there, but I cannot see the text anywhere.

Comment: If it shows up when you Ctrl-F it, then the code is executed properly. Then it's just a matter of CSS or HTML to make it appear in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(mail('myemail.co.uk', $email, $message))
    $sent_mail = true;
else
    $sent_mail = false;
```

And finally:

```
<?php
 if ($sent_mail) {
 echo 'Thank you. We will be in touch soon.';
 }
else
 echo 'Message cannot be send';
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. That should work but doesn't. Maybe because when the button is pressed the page is reloaded, so the thank you message doesn't show

Comment: `Thank you` message should be on the same page to display it to the user.

Comment: Thank you, that kind of works. When I use 'find' the web page says it is there, but I cannot see the text anywhere.

Comment: Search in `view source` of your web page.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning Boolean to $sent_mail and you set it to True.

```
<?php if($sent_mail){
echo "Email sent successfully";} ?>
```

Comment: Problem is something else, then !